# TeamReview installation issue

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

There is an open source product (code review tool for Visual Studio & TFS) [TeamReview](http://teamreview.codeplex.com/). I try to install TeamReview 2010 1.1.3 for Visual Studio 2010 Premium. I've started the installer (setup.exe), it've said that the installation has finished successfully. But when I start VS2010, I can't find TeamReview context menus. What do I do wrong?

Comment: Try to install Visual Studio SDK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is solved. The installer haven't copy add-in to the VS AddIns foolder. So, this is a solution:

1. Open the following file with a text editor: "%Program Files%\TeamReview\TeamReview (2010)\TeamReview.VSNetAddIn.Addin"
2. Replace inner text of Assembly element with the full path of TeamReview.VsNetAddIn.dll file, e.g. "c:\Program Files (x86)\TeamReview\TeamReview (2010)\TeamReview.VsNetAddIn.dll". Save changes.
3. Create folder %APPDATA%\Microsoft\MSEnvShared\AddIns if it doesn't exist.
4. Copy all files from c:\Program Files (x86)\TeamReview\TeamReview (2010)\ to %APPDATA%\Microsoft\MSEnvShared\AddIns